# How do I put an if statement inside the body of a PHPMailer code?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to put an if statement inside the body along with the html, but it's not working. I'm using PHPMailer, is something wrong with the code?

```
<?php

require  'email/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

extract($_POST);

$mail = new PHPMailer;


$mail ->isHTML(true);
$mail ->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail ->Body .="

if($result != null){
    echo "Name: " $result
}

";
```

I tried it the way Artem Medianyk said and it worked, but when I put the other variables that way, it didn't work.

```
$body = '';

if ($result_SRV_AA_A10_name_go != null) {
  $body = "Name: " . $result_SRV_AA_A10_name_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_A10_email_go != null) {
  $body = "E-mail: " . $result_SRV_AA_A10_email_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_A10_tel_go != null) {
  $body = "Telefone: " . $result_SRV_AA_A10_tel_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_B9_name_go != null) {
  $body = "Name: " . $result_SRV_AA_B9_name_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_B9_email_go != null) {
  $body = "E-mail: " . $result_SRV_AA_B9_email_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_B9_tel_go != null) {
  $body = "Telefone: " . $result_SRV_AA_B9_tel_go;
}

$body = json_encode($body);

$mail ->Body .= $body;
```

My idea is to check the answers that have been filled out and then send them in the best way by email. what could i do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this again:

```
$body = '';

if ($result_SRV_AA_A10_name_go != null) {
  $body .= "Name: " . $result_SRV_AA_A10_name_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_A10_email_go != null) {
  $body .= "E-mail: " . $result_SRV_AA_A10_email_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_A10_tel_go != null) {
  $body .= "Telefone: " . $result_SRV_AA_A10_tel_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_B9_name_go != null) {
  $body .= "Name: " . $result_SRV_AA_B9_name_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_B9_email_go != null) {
  $body .= "E-mail: " . $result_SRV_AA_B9_email_go;
}

if ($result_SRV_AA_B9_tel_go != null) {
  $body .= "Telefone: " . $result_SRV_AA_B9_tel_go;
}

$mail ->Body .= $body;
```

Comment: It worked!! I appreciate your help.. Can I do any style editing this way, maybe just skip a line between responses? Because they all came in the same line and tight

Comment: Yes, you can use $body.= "<p>Telephone: ". $result_SRV_ . "</p>";

Comment: Hey Artem, I asked another question related to this one, can you take a look and see if you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65457345/select-information-from-the-database-for-a-page-accessed-by-different-users

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php

require  'email/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

extract($_POST);

$result = {something};

$mail = new PHPMailer;


$mail ->isHTML(true);
$mail ->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$body = "";

if ($result != null) {
  $body = "Name: " . $result;
}

$body = json_encode($body);

$mail ->Body .= $body;
```

Comment: it worked well with one variable, but when I put the other variables that way, it didn't work. My idea is to check the answers that have been filled out and then send them in the best way by email. what could i do to achieve this?

Comment: @VitorFreitas but your question code only include the one var. So, Artem's answer is correct based on the details you supplied.

Comment: Please let me know all the possible situations which you want to fiter.